# How do I integrate it?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

Here, how to integrate it step by step?

$$I=\int\frac{x^2+x+1}{\sqrt{x^2+2x+3}} \ dx$$

**Solution:**

First let's Substitute, we got
$$x^2+2x+3=t^2$$
$$\implies {x}=\sqrt{t^2-2}-1$$
$$\implies dx=\frac{t}{\sqrt{t^2-2}}dt$$

Putting this back into the Integral followed by
$$I=\int\frac{x^2+2x+3-x-2}{\sqrt{x^2+2x+3}}dx$$
$$=\int\frac{t^2-(\sqrt{t^2-2}-1)-2}{\sqrt{t^2}}dx$$
$$=\int\frac{t^2-\sqrt{t^2-2}+1-2}{t}\frac{t}{\sqrt{t^2-2}}dt$$
$$=\int\frac{t^2-2+1-\sqrt{t^2-2}}{\sqrt{t^2-2}}dt$$
$$=\int\frac{t^2-2}{\sqrt{t^2-2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{t^2-2}}-1dt$$
$$=\int\sqrt{t^{2}-2}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{t^{2}-2}}-1dt$$

Since we all know,

$$\int\sqrt{x^2-a^2}dx=\frac{x}{2}\sqrt{x^2-a^2}-\ln\left(\left|\sqrt{x^2-a^2}+x\right|\right)$$

and $$\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2-a^2}}dx=\ln(x+\sqrt{x^2-a^2})$$
& $$a^2=(\sqrt{2})^2=2$$

*Now*

$$I=\frac{t}{2}\sqrt{t^2-2}-\ln(t+\sqrt{t^2-2})+\ln(t+\sqrt{t^2-2}-t+C$$
$$\implies I=\frac{t}{2}\sqrt{t^2-2}-t+C$$
$$=\frac{t}{2}\sqrt{t^2}-\frac{t}{2}\sqrt{2}-t+C$$
$$=\frac{t.t}{2}-\frac{t}{2}\sqrt{2}-t+C$$
$$=\frac{t^2-t\sqrt{2}-2t}{2}+C$$
$$=\frac{t(t-\sqrt{2}-2)}{2}+C$$
$$=\frac{(t-\sqrt{2}-2)}{2}t+C$$

Now Putting back ***x***'s value , we get,

$$I=\frac{\sqrt{x^2+2x+3}-\sqrt{2}-2}{2}\sqrt{x^2+2x+3}+C$$
$$=\frac{\sqrt{x^2+2x+1+2}-\sqrt{2}-2}{2}\sqrt{x^2+2x+3}+C$$
$$=\frac{\sqrt{(x+1)^2+2}-\sqrt{2}-2}{2}\sqrt{x^2+2x+3}+C$$
$$=\frac{(x+1)+\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{2}-2}{2}\sqrt{x^2+2x+3}+C$$
$$\implies I=\frac{x-1}{2}\sqrt{x^2+2x+3}+C$$

So , The solution is:

$$\fbox{$\int\frac{x^2+x+1}{\sqrt{x^2+2x+3}}dx=(\frac{x-1}{2})\sqrt{x^2+2x+3}+C$}$$

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it? Don't worry if it's wrong - that's what we're here for. [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question)'s a quick guide (if nothing else, read up the part on ["avoiding no-clue questions"](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933))

Comment: Also, don't get discouraged by the downvote. I downvoted the question and voted to close it because at the moment, it is not up to site standards (you have shown no work you did on your own). If you edit your question so that you show what you tried and how far you got, I will not only remove the downvote, I will add an upvote. Even if the question is closed, you can still edit it, and we will vote to reopen it.

Comment: Edited it, now see

Comment: You made no significant edit. All you did was add "dx" to the integral. Like I already said: *it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question*. You did not show any of your own attempts.

Comment: @hasnatrbm You need to show us some work you've done. Talk about where you got stuck, what you don't understand, etc. This isn't a place to just get HW answers, you gotta put in some effort too.

Comment: On [this site](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwi315zU3q71AhWHRfEDHZ9tDvMQFnoECAQQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.integral-calculator.com%2F&usg=AOvVaw0EjIVn1VmMoq2xzNu1PmAY), it is done as you wish. Why are you asking here?

Comment: I put some effort , now help to get rest , i mean putting back integral and simplification

Comment: I'm tempted to complete the square in the denominator to force a trig substitution. That may work.

Comment: Write the numerator as $(x^2+2x+3)-(x+1) -1$.

Comment: I got this $$\frac{t^2}{\sqrt{t^{2}-2}}-1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{t^{2}-2}}$$

Comment: have you tried Rene's method?  I think the aim is to get 3 integrals.  1 easily solved by sub, and the other 2 can be solved by completing the square and making trig subs, but are then standard integrals.

Comment: @Cato yeah , i know it . But I'm comfortable with this way

Answer (score 1):

Here is the full solution

First let's Substitute, we got
$$x^2+2x+3=t^2$$
$$\implies {x}=\sqrt{t^2-2}-1$$
$$\implies dx=\frac{t}{\sqrt{t^2-2}}dt$$

Putting this back into the Integral followed by
$$I=\int\frac{x^2+2x+3-x-2}{\sqrt{x^2+2x+3}}dx$$
$$=\int\frac{t^2-(\sqrt{t^2-2}-1)-2}{\sqrt{t^2}}dx$$
$$=\int\frac{t^2-\sqrt{t^2-2}+1-2}{t}\frac{t}{\sqrt{t^2-2}}dt$$
$$=\int\frac{t^2-2+1-\sqrt{t^2-2}}{\sqrt{t^2-2}}dt$$
$$=\int\frac{t^2-2}{\sqrt{t^2-2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{t^2-2}}-1dt$$
$$=\int\sqrt{t^{2}-2}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{t^{2}-2}}-1dt$$

Since we all know,

$$\int\sqrt{x^2-a^2}dx=\frac{x}{2}\sqrt{x^2-a^2}-\ln\left(\left|\sqrt{x^2-a^2}+x\right|\right)$$

and $$\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2-a^2}}dx=\ln(x+\sqrt{x^2-a^2})$$
& $$a^2=(\sqrt{2})^2=2$$

*Now*

$$I=\frac{t}{2}\sqrt{t^2-2}-\ln(t+\sqrt{t^2-2})+\ln(t+\sqrt{t^2-2}-t+C$$
$$\implies I=\frac{t}{2}\sqrt{t^2-2}-t+C$$
$$=\frac{t}{2}\sqrt{t^2}-\frac{t}{2}\sqrt{2}-t+C$$
$$=\frac{t.t}{2}-\frac{t}{2}\sqrt{2}-t+C$$
$$=\frac{t^2-t\sqrt{2}-2t}{2}+C$$
$$=\frac{t(t-\sqrt{2}-2)}{2}+C$$
$$=\frac{(t-\sqrt{2}-2)}{2}t+C$$

Now Putting back ***x***'s value , we get,

$$I=\frac{\sqrt{x^2+2x+3}-\sqrt{2}-2}{2}\sqrt{x^2+2x+3}+C$$
$$=\frac{\sqrt{x^2+2x+1+2}-\sqrt{2}-2}{2}\sqrt{x^2+2x+3}+C$$
$$=\frac{\sqrt{(x+1)^2+2}-\sqrt{2}-2}{2}\sqrt{x^2+2x+3}+C$$
$$=\frac{(x+1)+\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{2}-2}{2}\sqrt{x^2+2x+3}+C$$
$$\implies I=\frac{x-1}{2}\sqrt{x^2+2x+3}+C$$

So , The solution is:

$$\fbox{$\int\frac{x^2+x+1}{\sqrt{x^2+2x+3}}dx=(\frac{x-1}{2})\sqrt{x^2+2x+3}+C$}$$

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please do not duplicate a question with the same answer.  And do not vandalize your question.

Comment: @amwhy ok done . I'm new.

Comment: Please do not use two posts to answer one question, and then copy other users' answers to [this post of yours](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4355890/how-this-simplification-was-done-in-the-integral?noredirect=1).  That amounts to plagiarism.